# difference between local IP address and WiFi IP address(which is generally available android mobile setting about phone-status )

Tags: android

I am working on an app which uses the IP address of the device. I am getting the IP address using two ways:

The first way is:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
```

and the second way is:

```
public String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                    .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(inetAddress
                            .hashCode());
                    Log.i("Ipadress", "***** IP=" + ip);
                    return ip;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("error", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Both ways return different IP addresses. What is difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

Each network interface may (and most probably will) have a different IP address, because the interfaces connect to different networks. (i.e. WiFi network and Mobile network)

For debugging puposes you might remove `return ip;` for a moment and also print out `intf.getName()` with each ip address in order to print out all ips with their corresponding network interface name.